# Why should we use good conductors as electrodes of a capacitor?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, material-science, capacitance, conductors

I was asked if and why why should the electrodes of a capacitor should be good electrical conductors.

It seemed obvious to me that if I want to form a Helmholtz double layer (because that's what happens in the case that we were talking) we needed to have the highest charge density at the surface of the electrode.

If it was not a good electrical conductor, then the charge density at the surface would be very low.

However, I am not being capable of identifying a law/equation that can support this. How can I related surface charge density and conductivity, so I can easily state that good conductors will produce higher charge density?

Comment: If the resistance is increased, the capacitor becomes lossy, and the device becomes its own RC circuit. The capacitor only holds its charge due to the applied voltage; typically they are used as part of time-varying circuits, and its their dynamic behavior which is important. You seem to be only considering them as energy storage devices.

Comment: @PeterDiehr Yes, in this case I'm talking about a non-polar capacitor for a DC current. That analysis does not seems to make things clearer. For a dc application, a capacitor is defined as an infinite resistive element and so it would seem that a resistive material should be used... My problem is only on the electrodes. How can I show that better conductivity will lead to higher surface charge density?

Comment: It won't help. Holding more charge requires an increase in capacitance at the given voltage. Increasing resistance decreases voltage, but does not change the capacitance.

Comment: @PeterDiehr is correct - a higher conductivity electrode does not increase the capacitance. However, consider trying to build a capacitor using insulating electrodes - it is kind of hard to get the charge where it needs to go. Poor conductors introduce resistive elements in the lumped capacitor model, meaning losses, a different complex impedance, and the possibility mentioned of self-resonance.

Comment: Geeze, you seem to be making this too complicated. Start with a perfect capacitor and add a resistor in series with the capacitor. Now charging with a DC current takes longer to charge the capacitor, and power is lost as heat. The capacitor will still take as much charge and the charge loss is constant.